# Is it possible to set up an API to serve html from another domain?

Tags: rest, http, server, cross-domain

I'm curious whether if it's possible to set up a server to respond with html fetched from another domain rather than simply redirect the requester to that domain.
For example, I set up a simple node express server that has a GET route /google, which fetches google.com, and then responds with the response from the fetch. However, in this case, it does not respond with the google webpage as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only possible but quite common especially in larger server environments.  The term you are looking for is reverse-proxy.

> Proxying is typically used to distribute the load among several servers, seamlessly show content from different websites, or pass requests for processing to application servers over protocols other than HTTP.
>
> Source: [https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/](https://web.archive.org/web/20211224150647/https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Most major web servers support it.

More than likely the response you're getting from google (and passing on) is some kind of redirection.  Try it with a static web page of your own to rule out any redirection shenanigans.